# Is it possible to write code in one version of styles.xml and have the other versions reference that code?

Tags: android, xml, styles

If I am developing an app app that could use any version of styles.xml is it possible to write code in one version of this file and have the other versions reference that code, rather then having to repeat the code multiple times?

I am using Eclipse, which has multiple versions of styles.xml:

res -> values -> styles.xml

res -> values-v11 -> styles.xml

res -> values-v14 -> styles.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes things declared in lower api level versions can be accessed.